# Text between two figure in LaTex

Tags: latex

How can i insert text between two figure like photo below ??

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `minipage`s. This way you won't have any problems with text spanning multiple lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
\centering
text

some more text
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.33\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\end{minipage}% 
  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you , it worked , but there is a small problem , the pictures is large , when i resize its by [width=0.4\linewidth] , the first image take long space with text ???

Comment: Instead of changing the width of the image itself, make it's minipage smaller, e.g. `\begin{minipage}{.2\textwidth}` or whatever width you like

Comment: Thank you soooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo much , it works well now

Answer (score 1):

A tabular environment would be simplest:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{lcr}
  \includegraphics{figure} &
  TEXT TEXT TEXT &
  \includegraphics{figure}
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Better don't use a file type for the graphic, this way latex will automatically select the file which is best suited for the engine you use.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Good point, thanks.